# ajax call before changing page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Example code:

```
        $.ajax({
                url: someUrl,
                data: someData,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () { },
        });                

        window.location = urlToGoTo;
```

Lets say the above code runs when the user clicks a button.

Since the ajax call is asynchronous, what will happen when code such the above runs ? Using a tool like Fiddler, it looks like sometimes the ajax call succeeds, and sometimes it never gets called (i.e. the current web page is changed before the ajax call gets a chance to run).

In cases like this, should you always wait for the ajax call to complete  before setting window.location (e.g. in the ajax "complete" event) ?

Just trying to get some insight into what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the redirect in the success callback

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrl,
    data: someData,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
        window.location = urlToGoTo;
    }
});
```

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

You must include the redirection link code inside the ajax call, especially, inside the success function:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: someUrl,
                data: someData,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () { 
                window.location = urlToGoTo;
                },
                error:function(){
                alert("Error Occurred!"); 
                }
        });
```